# Loading a JSON file into a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
 var myJSON ;
$.getJSON("../json.json",function(data){
    myJSON =data;
});
```

I have tried using $.getJSON() using jquery,however the data it returns is always null. I do not understand why. The path to the JSON file is correct.

Comment: It expects to be an ajax request.
You need to reference this json from a remote server.
you can use this URL for example 
http://ip.jsontest.com/ .

 For more detailed information
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Are you sure the file is really in that path (not available on your filesystem) and its format is correct (it is really a proper JSON file)?

Comment: Yes definitely sure it is correct path and file

Answer (score 1):

This code should work if the path is correct... however if you are declaring myJSON outside of the callback function probably you are trying to use it outside... before the callback function has been called:

```
var myJSON; // why are you declaring that here?
$.getJSON("../json.json",function(data){
    myJSON =data;
    console.log('Within the callback function: '+myJSON);
});

console.log('Outside the callback function: '+myJSON) // this is ALWAYS null
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON data isn't immediately available after you make a request.
`$.getJSON` returns before the data gets downloaded and just calls the provided callback when it's finished.

You need to do

```
$.getJSON("../json.json",function(myJSON){
    // do something with myJSON
});
```

If you really need a synchronous request, use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with the parameter `async` to `false`.

Also check if your JSON is valid. There is a difference, how you can define arrays and objects in JavaScript and what is proper JSON.
e.g. `[1,2,3,]` should be `[1,2,3]`, `{one:1}` should be `{"one":1}`.

Comment: He is using data inside callback function only. check question again.

Comment: I think the downvote has been too quick here.The code in the question does not check myJSON, so we don't really know where the OP is using that value

Comment: @DexTer I don't see any usage of the data inside the callback. He is just assigning it to a variable outside the callback, that's why I assume he is trying to use it outside the callback after the `$.getJSON` call.